# Dynamically changed content doesn't reflect inside the Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I've simplified my query in the example below but I'm trying to achieve something similar. Basically, the radio button values are applied to the next button's data-url attribute and the modal will load content based on the URL, but in the snippet here I've just displayed the URL in the modal body. As you can see when you select a radio and click next whatever you select first is displayed and any subsequent choices are ignored as the variable still holds the first selected option. However, the button has the correct URL, it's just not passing to the modal correctly. Just wondering how to fix the issue so the modal displays the correct URL I've selected in the radio button. Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks.

```js
$('.js-url-check').on('change', function() {
  $('.js-url-btn').attr('data-url', this.value);
});

$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  var button = $(e.relatedTarget);
  var modalBody = $(this).find('.modal-body');
  modalBody.html(button.data('url'));
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="margin: 20px">
    <div class="form-group">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Select URL</legend>
        <div class="form-check form-check--radio">
          <input class="form-check-input js-mandatory js-url-check" id="google" name="SearchEngine" type="radio" value="https://google.com">
          <label for="google" class="form-check-label">Google</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check--radio">
          <input class="form-check-input js-mandatory js-url-check" id="yahoo" name="SearchEngine" type="radio" value="https://yahoo.com">
          <label for="yahoo" class="form-check-label">Yahoo</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check--radio">
          <input class="form-check-input js-mandatory js-url-check" id="msn" name="SearchEngine" type="radio" value="https://msn.com">
          <label for="msn" class="form-check-label">MSN</label>
        </div>
        <a href="#" data-url="" class="btn btn-primary js-url-btn mt-4" data-toggle="modal" target="_blank" data-target="#exampleModal">Next</a>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="exampleModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple fix in the end - just had to change the 'attr' to 'data'.